# How do I include a Map of Strings as attributes in an xml tag using Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

```
val name = "Name";
val value = "Value";
val map = Map(id -> "5", class -> "Nice");
textfield(name, value, map);


def textfield(name: String, value: String, attributes: Map = {}){ //=> Any
    val xml = <text name={name} value={value} {attributes.?} />;
}
```

I'm trying to have that produce

```
<text name="Name" value="Value" id="5", class="nice" />
```

I'd like to use xml literals if possible, but If not Which xml classes would I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import scala.xml.{Attribute, Text, Elem}
def textfield(name: String, value: String, attributes: Map[String, String] = Map()) = {
  val elem: Elem = <text name={name} value={value} />
  (elem /: attributes) {
    case (el, att) => el % Attribute(att._1, Text(att._2), xml.Null)
  }
}
```